# How to connect to Google SQL from React App hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a react App that runs on Google App engine. This also has a MYSQL connection which was working fine on localhost (XAMPP MYSQL Database).
I created a SQL instance on Google Cloud and have the Instance Connection Name. But I am getting unable to connect errors.

Here is my application code that was working on Local. Below is my env.js

```
  "MYSQL_HOST": "localhost",
  "MYSQL_USER": "GoogleDBUser",
  "MYSQL_PASSWORD": "GoogleDBPassword",
  "MYSQL_DATABASE": "GoogleDB1",
```

Here is code for MYSQL connection:

```
// RETUNS MYSQL DATABASE

const mysql = require('mysql'),
  { error } = require('handy-log'),
  { MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE } = process.env

// CREATES A DB CONNECTION
const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: MYSQL_HOST,
  user: MYSQL_USER,
  password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: MYSQL_DATABASE,
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
})

module.exports = db
```

What else is needed to connect to the Google MYSQL ? I dont know where in the above code to add the Google SQL Instance name.

Comment: Check if Google App engine instance is permitted to connect with DB, more info here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip

Comment: @RafalWiliński - `Apps in this project: All authorized.` - Both are in same project.  Is there any code change required to connect to that DB in my code above?